# Does Azure Function App restrict outgoing HTTP calls from inside the function to HTTPS only?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have a NodeJS Azure Function App that is up and running, and recently I have had to change the endpoint of one HTTP call to another URL.

This URL is verified to be working and returning expected responses. However once the previous HTTPS URL on Azure application settings was replaced with the new non-HTTPS URL, everything breaks and the function only shows as "Function started" repeatedly. Changing the environment variable back to the old HTTPS URL fixes it.

So we are suspecting that it is an issue with Azure Function App possibly restricting all outgoing HTTP calls to HTTPS only, but we couldn't find anything in the docs or on the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Azure Functions do not limit the outbound calls to HTTPS-only. Are you sure your SSL certificate is valid (and signed by a recognized CA)?

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be the case, we've worked it out.